# sqlite odbc getting hour min. sec

Tags: sqlite, odbc, timestamp

I am using [sqliteodbc](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and for some reason it won't get the hours, minutes, and seconds. I bind the column using this:

```
SQLBindCol(hTimeStampNotes, 5, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, &(noteTimeStamp.submitTime), 16, &junkLong);
```

noteTimeStamp.submitTime is a time stamp data type:

```
typedef struct tagTimeStampType {//TIMESTAMP_STRUCT 
    short year;
    short month;
    short day;
    short hour;
    short minute;
    short second;
    unsigned int fraction; 
} TimeStampType;//TIMESTAMP_STRUCT;
```

My hour, minute, second, and fraction always come out as 0. This works for me using an access database. Has anybody else had this problem? I could have sworn that this was working for me a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I couldn't figure out why this was happening here is how I got around it:

first I added an array to the end of the type

```
typedef struct tagTimeStampType//TIMESTAMP_STRUCT 
   {
   short year;
   short month;
   short day;
   short hour;
   short minute;
   short second;
   unsigned int fraction; 
   char  timeStampStr[20];
   } TimeStampType;//TIMESTAMP_STRUCT;
```

then added #ifdef

```
#ifdef SQLITE
   SQLBindCol(hTimeStampNotes, 5, SQL_C_CHAR, noteTimeStamp.submitTime.timeStampStr, 20, &junkLong);
#else
   SQLBindCol(hTimeStampNotes, 5, SQL_C_TIMESTAMP, &(noteTimeStamp.submitTime), 16, &junkLong);
```

and just paced the string myself with a little function

```
void TimeStampPrep(TimeStampType *timeStamp)
{
#ifdef SQLITE
   timeStamp->year = atoi(timeStamp->timeStampStr);
   timeStamp->month = atoi(&(timeStamp->timeStampStr[5]));
   timeStamp->day = atoi(&(timeStamp->timeStampStr[8]));
   timeStamp->hour = atoi(&(timeStamp->timeStampStr[11]));
   timeStamp->minute = atoi(&(timeStamp->timeStampStr[14]));
   timeStamp->second = atoi(&(timeStamp->timeStampStr[17]));
   return;
#else
   return;
#endif
}
```

I am still trying to figure out why this my original code wouldn't work with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Years passed but nothing changed :)

For those who would like to know the actual reason:

...from sqlite3odbc.c

```
     if (p->coldef && p->coldef <= 16) {
         sprintf(p->strbuf, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00.000",
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->year,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->month,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->day,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->hour,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->minute);
     } else if (p->coldef && p->coldef <= 19) {
         sprintf(p->strbuf, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.000",
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->year,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->month,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->day,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->hour,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->minute,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->second);
     } else {
         sprintf(p->strbuf, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->year,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->month,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->day,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->hour,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->minute,
                 ((TIMESTAMP_STRUCT *) p->param)->second,
                 len);
     }
```